# What's the difference between linearly polarised and plane-polarised waves?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, terminology, polarization

To explain polarisation, my book gives an example of a transverse wave in a string, and explains as:

> Since each point on the string moves on a straight line, the wave is also referred to as a *linearly polarised wave*. Further, the string always remains confined to the x-y plane and therefore it is also referred to as a *plane polarised wave*

The image given is somewhat like this: [image]

The definitions for both these terms are different, so it seems to me that they are not same. But I wasn't able to find an example which illustrates the difference between these two.

I found [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-linearly-polarised-and-plane-polarised-light) Quora question, but the answers don't seem convincing.

So what exactly is the difference between a linearly polarised wave and a plane-polarised wave?  Because according to me, a linearly polarised wave will oscillate in only one plane.

Comment: I've always taken them as synonymous.  The main distinction is between plane [linear] and circularly polarized light, which doesn't oscillate in any one plane.

Comment: linear polarisation only talks about direction of oscillation of electric field for example y polarised light has it electric field amplitude only in y-direction and it direction propogation is not specified . we need plane of polarisation to specify a waves oscillation as well as direction of propogation. y polarised light can propogate in x-direction or in z- direction. this distinction (linear polarisation and plane polarisation )  is required to know direction of oscillation as well as direction of propogation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linearly polarized wave is same as plane polarized wave.
Why we call it linearly polarized ? 
Because oscillation taking place along a line.
Why we call it plane polarized  ?
Since oscillation taking place along one axis & the wave is forward in motion along another axis. Two axes are used , so called plane.

Answer (score 0):

Linearly polarized wave Oscillate in a single plane and the magnitude of electric field vector varies sinusoidally as a function of time.

Circularly polarized wave have their magnitude of electric field vector constant, but their phase change periodically as a function of time.(i.e. the electric field vector rotate periodically as a function of time)

Comment: In your answer, shouldn't it be _displacement(or something else) varies sinusoidally as a function of time_ instead of _amplitude varies sinusoidally as a function of time_

Comment: I'm sorry. I had written amplitude instead of writing electric field vector.